# Will same transaction guarantee data visibility

Tags: java, oracle

Java application code use Oracle in the backend, and we are passing transaction object around. For example in part 1 we use that transaction to insert records into table A, later in part 2 we try to access those records in the same transaction, is it possible the records are not there? To be safe should we do a commit in part A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a transaction, read operations see the world as updated by the last write operation, so you absolultely **don't need** to commit (after all, that's the whole point of transactions!).

For relaxed [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_uncommitted) (that allow better performance), a transaction could see changes not yet committed by other transactions.